# Is it possible to use NSMetadataQuery when iCloud is disabled?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, icloud

I can't seem to get NSMetadataQuery to work when I disable iCloud. I put in a valid search URL, but it never registers as finished:

```
//Check for iCloud
NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] 
               URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
if (ubiq) {
    NSLog(@"iCloud access at %@", ubiq);
    self.query = [[[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self.query setSearchScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:
                                 NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDataScope]];
    _isiCloudEnabled = YES;
} else {
    NSLog(@"No iCloud access");
    //Get the doc directory
    NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    self.query = [[[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self.query setSearchScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path],nil]];
    _isiCloudEnabled = NO;
}

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: 
                     @"%K like %@", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey, @"*.adoc"];
[self.query setPredicate:pred];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
 addObserver:self 
 selector:@selector(queryDidFinishGathering:) 
 name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification 
 object:self.query];

[self.query startQuery];
```

queryDidFinishGathering: never gets called. When iCloud is enabled, it always gets called. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem but I am using the ARC in project. This is solved by setting the ivar to self.query variable.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMetadataQuery *query;
```

I think for your problem as you are not using the ARC, you may need to do following things:

1. remove the autorelease and manually release when finish the work.
2. you need to set the property

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMetadataQuery *query;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS5, `NSMetadataQuery` 's search scope can only be set to ubiquitous things (`NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope` and `NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDataScope`) so using it with iCloud disabled would be unuseful.

As you are probably guessing the reason `queryDidFinishGathering` is never called is because of your query scope, local directories are not supported yet (but suspiciously not throwing exceptions or errors :) )

In my opinion NSMetadataQuery class is not fully ported to iOS, in OSX more scopes can be set , more kinds of `NSPredicate` can be set, `NSSortDescriptors` work, etc.